# Working with Brands in Kentico E-Commerce

Tags: kentico

I want to be able to list all the brands in the eCommerce area of our kentico website and display the logo for the brand. I cant see any documented way to get this. I can get BrandInfo which has a Thumbnail GUID but this seems useless when used with the MediaFileRepository.

Answer (score 2):

This thumbnail GUID is not from **Media File** class, but from another class - **Meta File**. You can find it via **MetaFileInfoProvider** by MetaFileGUID. The table in the database is **CMS_MetaFile**.